# How to prevent pandas converting the original database date format to pandas date format

Tags: pandas, date, netezza

My Date format is in the database in this format : **9/15/2017 5:01:44 AM**

But when read_sql using pandas the date format become like this **2017-09-15 05:01:44**

Two problems here:

1. First one is **/** changed to **-**
2. Second one is mm/dd/yyyy changed
   tod yyyy-mm-dd. year becomes the first element.

The main problem is I have date columns in different formats in different tables and some are only dates and others are date and timestamps.

I do not have idea on what the format looks like.
Is there any way while read the data to preserve the original format?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from your database and what is the column type?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try: `strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'test': {0: '23/07/2020', 1: '23/07/2020'}})
print (df)
        test
0  23/07/2020
1  23/07/2020

df['test'] = pd.to_datetime(df.test)
print (df)
        test
0 23-07-2020
1 23-07-2020

df['test1'] = df['test'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
print (df)
        test       test1
0 23-07-2020  23/07/2020
1 23-07-2020  23/07/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: I’m 99% sure you cannot (even though I’m only able to google ‘pandas’)

The slightly longer answer is that your question does not make sense: all data is stored internally in the system as binary values. Apart from the ‘storage format’ (which applies to the database SERVER) you should focus on the ‘display format’ which mostly applies to the client software you choose to look at the data with. Please that is true for all data types, including dates, but integers, floating point, strings all have a ‘storage format’ that is VERY different from the ‘display format’.

Furthermore all software system like SAS, R, python (or Pandas) are able to store data in files too, and the ‘storage format’ for each data type may in theory be the same as in the database, but expect differences.
The client may even have different ‘display formats’ for the same data type depending on where the data came from (even though I would consider that bad behavior)

Does this make sense to you?